# Add class to form-group elements

Tags: fluentbootstrap

I am trying to have fields arranged in 2 columns within a horizontal form, but I cannot add a `col-md-6` class to a `form-group` element.

The form should like something like this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Giovax/xvfcns13/2/).

I have checked the source code, and column size classes are **explicitly** removed from the `form-group` and applied to a new contained `div` element.
The net result is that the inner control is resized properly, but, as the `form-group` is still considered a 12 units sized element, the next control is placed in a different line.

I was able to achieve the layout I wanted using:

```
@Html.Bootstrap().Div().AddCss( Css.ColMd6 )
     .AddChild( form.Input( "divChild", "Div Child" ) )
```

or

```
@Html.Bootstrap().Div().AddCss( Css.ColMd6 )
     .AddContent( form.Input( "divContent", "Div Content" ) )
```

or

```
using (Html.Bootstrap().Div().AddCss( Css.ColMd6).Begin() )
{
    @form.Input( "divusing", "Div Using" )
}
```

or

```
<div class="@Css.ColMd6" >
    @form.Input( "htmldiv", "HTML Div" )
</div>
```

but I'd like a cleaner syntax like the following:

```
@form.Input( "name", "label" ).AddGroupCss( Css.ColMd6 )
```

but this would require adding a new extension **AND** not removing col sizing classes from `form-group` elements. Would this be possible?

Alternatively, can you suggest any other ways to get a multi columns layout in FluentBootstrap?

Comment: Adding the extra extension wouldn't be a problem, a flag could just be set to prevent the class removal from the containing `form-group`.

Comment: However, I'd like to understand the actual problem a little more - are you able to post a screen shot of what you want it to look like? In the examples above, we've got a half-width control, but what about the controls around it? Should this control just be in a half-width column with other arbitrary content?

Comment: Dave, I have added a Fiddle with the desired outcome.